# Using bits directly in python

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I want to manipulate the binary number directly in python. For example I have decimal number 18. I was able to convert number into binary using

```
seed =bin(18)
```

but problem is I want to xor few of its bits.If I access this seed using array indexing I cant xor them as it is of type 'str'. How can simply take decimal number convert into binary and play with its bits?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Numbers are generally already represented in binary. They are printed to the screen in their decimal representations. Use the Python's [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) on the `int` objects to manipulate bits.

Comment: Work with `18` instead of `bin(18)`

Comment: Thing is I want to implement 6 bit shift register. xor few bits on this register and feed it to its input it. For example If I have a= 010000 I will xor a[1]  which is 1 with a[2] which is 1 and get output 1. After feeding this 0 to input new number will be 010001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bitwise operations directly on integers. You can convert between binary strings and integers for printing/debugging by using `bin` as you already know, and converting a string to binary using `int(binary_string, 2)`.

```
seed = bin(18)  # 0b10010
bitmask = '01101'
xor_result = 18 ^ int(bitmask, 2)
print(bin(xor_result))  # 0b11111
```

Comment: Thing is I want to implement 6 bit shift register. xor few bits on this register and feed it to its input it. For example If I have a= 010000 I will xor a[1]  which is 1 with a[2] which is 1 and get output 1. After feeding this 0 to input new number will be 010001.

Comment: Right - so if you want to work with a string you can, but you will need to do the actual bitwise operations on integers. You can cast `'0'` or `'1'` to ints before you do the operation.

Comment: Thanks this helps. One more thing. I want to convert it into binary for specific number of bits. If I use check=format(a,'b') where a is 16 it gives me 5 bits binary: 10000. What if I want sepcific number of bits say 6 or 8?

Comment: You can use zfill: `format(a, 'b').zfill(6)`. Or, you can use string formatting: `'{:06b}'.format(16)`.

Comment: Thanks karin that helps a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use bitwise operators directly on numbers.

For instance `18 & 3` gets you `2`, `18 | 3` gets you `19`, `1 << 5` gets you `32`. The fact that the human readable representation when you print the number is a decimal number doesn't change the fact that at an underlying level the numbers are all just stored and operated on as binary numbers.

`bin` just gives you the binary representation of a number as a string. While that's useful for debugging or human output, you generally won't want to use it for bit manipulation directly.

Comment: Thing is I want to implement 6 bit shift register. xor few bits on this register and feed it to its input it. For example If I have a= 010000 I will xor a[1]  which is 1 with a[2] which is 1 and get output 1. After feeding this 0 to input new number will be 010001.